# Find the domain for which $[\sin^{-1}x]+[\cos^{-1}x]$=0

Tags: trigonometry

Find the domain for which $[\sin^{-1}x]+[\cos^{-1}x]=0$
where $[\cdot]$ represents the greatest integer fraction.

We know that $\sin^{-1}x\in \left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$&
$\cos^{-1}x\in [0,\pi]$ but dont know how to proceed

Answer (score 1):

Possible values for the first term are $-1,0,1$ and those for the second term are $0,1,2,3$. There sum can be $0$ only when the first term is $-1$ and the second term is $+1$ or both terms are $0$. Can you proceed?

Comment: It become more complicated

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi It has become more simple. Geetha's comment / answer is an improvement. You should explain why it is now harder / still hard for you, to get proper help